# Why does ssh connection to gitlab not work (while http push and clone work fine)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

I run a x86 raring ringtail on a old pc and having installed bitnami gitlab 5.3.

Here is my error msg when trying to push the first master branch in SSH mode:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

(it works in http protocol with the gitlab web dashboard credentials)

1. I have launched `bitnami-installer.run` with `root` user so I think all the files went in `/opt` instead of `/home` (this was the good procedure?)
2. I didn't have a `git` user before installing GitLab since I heard it could make a confusion in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` files and other permissions.
3. When I run `ssh -T git@my-server.com` it says `permission denied (public key)` but the pub key on my client computer is also in `.ssh/authorized_keys`?
4. `authorized_keys` has the proper content also, with for each line:

   ```
   command= "/opt/gitlab/apps/"
   ```
5. I have also noticed that I cannot display the content of `authorized_keys` file with a `sudo -su git nano authorized_keys` because:

   > the user is not in the sudoers file.
6. But `sudo /opt/gitlab/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/check` returns `ok` for each verification (gitlab api, acces, repo and `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (because i have set in th config.yml gitlab_url to : http://myserver.com/gitlab (local server ip address) instead of http://loopbackaddress.com/gitlab). I have noticed that i have « two versions » of the gitlab-shell directory, one in `/opt` and one in `/home` and i don't know if it it is the appropriated demeanor ?
7. When i try a `ssh -Tv` it seems the ssh server does not even accept my key, fail to authenticate and return « permission denied » at last.
8. Also nothing special in the `/var/log/auth.log` files other than s`shd[number] : connection closed by IP address`.
9. The authorized_keys file path is set to the correct absolute url in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file (/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys)
10. And finally i am unable to debug with « bundle exec bin/rake » since i am not able to make my ubuntu install all the required pacakge to execute bundle.

I am almost sure it's either a simple ssh misconfiguration or something wrong when invoking the `command="/opt/...../gitlab-shell"` in the authorized_keys file

PS: using git with HTTP protocole would be enough for my home server but the interest of the gitlab dashboard is to easily add a contributors by filling the ssh key in the web form and using ssh after

Comment: Your problem might be comming from a permission issue. Does every single file inside of /home/git belongs to the user git and group git?

Answer (score 5):

I've got the following error trying to clone repo via ssh from freshly installed gitlab:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Solution was found at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#ssh

Check ssh log /var/log/auth.log and if you find error:

```
User git not allowed because account is locked
```

then edit `/etc/shadow` and change `git:!: to git:*:`

P.S. 
In my case on CentOS 6.5 it was /var/log/secure and git:!!:

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my issue. At some point my git user was disabled and nothing ever warned or told me.

Comment: Thanks alot! Finally found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I had a same error. searched and tried many way. It didn't work.
Then, i found the answer in this site [http://georgik.sinusgear.com[1](http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2013/06/01/gitlab-could-not-read-from-remote-repository/). It worked for me.

My gitlab's version is 6.6.4.

Do as below:

1. find port unicorn run on:

> sudo emacs /home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb
>   
>   scroll to # listen on both a Unix domain socket and a TCP port and found that:
>   listen "127.0.0.1:port", :tcp_nopush => true

1. edit config.yml

> sudo emacs /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
>   
>   change 
>   gitlab_url: "your-domain"

to

> gitlab_url: "127.0.0.1:[port]"

restart gitlab

> sudo service gitlab stop
>
> sudo service gitlab start

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the .ssh folder.

Login as the git user and set with

```
sudo su - git
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/authorized_keys
```

If still having issues use the verbose output from ssh to gain more info

```
ssh -v  ssh -T git@my-server.com
```

(Also it could be a selinux context issue if selinux is enabled and enforcing, see [this blog](http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2012/11/02/selinux-solutions-fixing-a-newly-provisioned-server-that-refuses-ssh-key-based-login/))

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add my public key to the /home/git/repositories/.ssh/authorized_keys. The authoried_keys in /home/git/.ssh seems to not be used.

1. Add your public key to authorized_keys

   ```
   cat id_rsa.pub >> /home/git/repositories/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
2. Ensure git is the owner of the file

   ```
   chown git /home/git/repositories/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
3. Ensure group is git

   ```
   chgrp git /home/git/repositories/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
4. Set file mode bits

   ```
   chmod 600 /home/git/repositories/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```