# Gitlab, Permission denied (publickey), version 6-4 stable

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
exists.

Gitlab version 6-4 stable

```
root@gitlab:/home/git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p353
Gem Version:    2.0.14
Bundler Version:1.5.2
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.4.3
Revision:   38397db
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://gitlab.xxx.xxx
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.xxx.xxx/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.xxx.xxx/some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.8.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git



root@gitlab:/home/git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.9 ? ... OK (1.8.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... 
Alexander  / Test ... repository is empty
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.2.12
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... 
Alexander  / Test ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
Alexander  / Test ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.5)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

And trying to push

root@gitlab:/home/git/repositories/test# git push origin master

> **Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
>   the repository exists.**

shh -vv git@xxx.xxx

```
 alex@xxxxxxx:~$ ssh -vv git@gitlab.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.xxx.xxx [192.168.0.40] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2047
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2047
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Host 'gitlab.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alex/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f8d86afa4f0),
debug2: key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 276
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitlab.xxx.xxx ([192.168.0.40]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to gitlab.xxx.xxx closed.
Transferred: sent 4088, received 2432 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 14872.5, received 8847.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

alex@xxxxx:~$ ssh git@gitlab.xxx.xxx
**PTY allocation request failed on channel 0**
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
Connection to gitlab.xxx.xx closed.

I tried with 5.4 stable and the same problem on production server.

But when for the sake of interest I installed 5.4 on local test server with virtual box and It works fine. Now I am even had compared everything, but It does not push on production server. Looks like this problem is related to SSH.

I searched already a lot, but all solutions I tried did not work in my case. I have already no idea, feels like it is kind of software bug...

I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance! 
Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting permission denied (public key) on gitlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427498/getting-permission-denied-public-key-on-gitlab)

Answer (score 18):

Try also pushing to the `https` url instead of the `ssh` this can save you lot of trouble - for example use this:

`git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/someuser/algorithm-excercises.git`

instead of:

`git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:someuser/algorithm-excercises.git`

Answer (score 9):

I found this after searching alot. It will work perfectly fine for me.

1. Go to "Git Bash" just like cmd.
2. Type `ssh-keygen`
3. Press enter.
4. It will ask you to save the key to the specific directory.
5. Press enter. It will prompt you to type password or enter without password.
6. The public key will be created to the specific directory.
7. Now go to the directory and open `.ssh` folder.
8. You'll see a file `id_rsa.pub`. Open it on notepad. Copy all text from it.
9. Go to https://gitlab.com/profile/keys .
10. Paste here in the "key" textfield.
11. Now click on the "Title" below. It will automatically get filled.
12. Then click "Add key".

Now give it a shot and it will work for sure.

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42556216/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score 7):

Hi I had a similar problem (it was after adding new ssh key to a newly created user)
I fixed it regenerating authorized_keys which was corrupted

cd /home/git/gitlab

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production
This will rebuild an authorized_keys file.
You will lose any data stored in authorized_keys file.
Do you want to continue (yes/no)? yes
```

Comment: Thank you for replay! It does not work for me unfortunately. All the same with "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0"

Comment: Then I'd suggest filing an issue in github, they tend to be quick to awnser: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues?labels=Merge+requests&page=1&state=open

Comment: Hithwen, thanks a lot! My issue is also now at GitHub https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6104

Comment: same issue, using the turnkey linux VM . This answer worked for me. no need to touch  /home/git/repositories/.ssh/authorized_keys manually in my case

Answer (score 2):

I posted an answer to a similar question

[Why does ssh connection to gitlab not work (while http push and clone work fine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726281/unable-to-make-a-ssh-connection-to-gitlab-but-http-push-and-clone-are-working/22747572#22747572)

which involves adding your public key to

```
/home/git/repositories/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and make public key:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "yourmail@mail.com" -b 4096`

go to your ssh rsa folder in your system: 
on Mac go to GO to Folder and type this address:

```
~/.ssh
```

then open it with text editor and copy the key

then go to gitlab setting shh key and pate it there
https://gitlab.com/profile/keys/2346923

then try again

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding .ssh folder in repositories worked for me so I have done this:

```
sudo -u git -H ln -s /home/git/.ssh /home/git/repositories/
```

Now all users can add the key from gitlab web and use ssh.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have an existing SSH key pair in local.**

Go to your home directory, then go to the `.ssh/` subdirectory. If the `.ssh/` subdirectory doesn't exist,
you are either not in the home directory, or you haven't used ssh before.

If not exist, You need to Generate an SSH key pair in `.ssh/` subdirectory:

1. `cd ~`
2. `cd .ssh/`
3. `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "<comment>"`

Then just press enter to finish.