# Getting permission denied (public key) on gitlab

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

My problem is that I can't push or fetch from GitLab. However, I can clone (via HTTP or via SSH). I get this error when I try to push :

> Permission denied (publickey) fatal : Could not read from remote repository

From all the threads I've looked, here is what I have done :

- Set up an SSH key on my computer and added the public key to GitLab
- Done the config --global for username and email
- Cloned via SSH and via HTTP to check if it would resolve the issue
- Done the ssh -T git@gitlab.com command

If you have any insight about how to resolve my issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: run `ssh -vvvv git@gitlab.com` to see if it picks up the SSH key

Comment: Did you add the SSH key via https://gitlab.com/profile/keys ?

Comment: @ Nils Werner : I get a  lot of lines when I do this command, but one of them is "Authentification succeeded (publickey)"

Comment: @ Akram Fares : Yes I did

Comment: Do you have permissions to read from the repo, and is there something in the repo?

Comment: @ Nils Werner : It is my repo, I am a master of it. And there is only a README.md in the repo right now.

Comment: What about `GIT_SSH=ssh -vvv git push` over `ssh`?

Comment: Unfortunatly I won't be able to test your command, I created a new local repo and cloned in that one. Now everything workds. Thanks for your help.

Comment: make sure you are not running `sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:project/somethiing.git`, otherwise ssh will look in `/root/.ssh` instead of the key you uploaded `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: In my case, I fixed it by restarting the GITLab instance (docker).

Comment: I solved the same problem by adding a key to agent via "ssh-add ~/.ssh/the_key" followed by authorising they key by phrase. This is the private part of what I added to GitLab.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858817/how-to-use-https-with-gitlab-com

Answer (score 603, accepted):

I found this after searching a lot. It will work perfectly fine for me.

1. Go to "Git Bash" just like cmd. Right click and "Run as Administrator".
2. Type `ssh-keygen`
3. Press enter.
4. It will ask you to save the key to the specific directory.
5. Press enter. It will prompt you to type password or enter without password.
6. The public key will be created to the specific directory.
7. Now go to the directory and open `.ssh` folder.
8. You'll see a file `id_rsa.pub`. Open it on notepad. Copy all text from it.
9. Go to https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys or
10. Paste here in the "key" textfield.
11. Now click on the "Title" below. It will automatically get filled.
12. Then click "Add key".

Now give it a shot and it will work for sure.

Comment: In case you're lost in copying the pub file into clipboard. try the following: `type %userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | clip`

Comment: in windows 10 if you do need to find .ssh\id_rsa.pub you can type this 
**cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**
on git bash it will show you the "Key" , so you could copy and paste it to text field in https://gitlab.com/profile/keys

Comment: Make sure to do this: `ssh-add filename`(with-path if not in the rsa dir) after following above steps

Comment: I did this, problem is not fixed, getting permissions denied

Comment: Ok it works for "Clone with SSH" case but it does not solve the denied issue for "Clone with HTTPS" case.

Comment: Referencing @Blasanka 's answer `ssh-add filename` where `filename` is the file WITHOUT `.pub` at the end. You'll be prompt the password you've generated during ssh key creation to add your identity

Comment: In my case,  https://gitlab.com/profile/keys was showing page not found error. So, I tried with https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys/ which worked fine.

Comment: If you customize the file name (not the `id_rsa`). Make sure to do `ssh-add filename` as @Blasanka mentioned above

Comment: this is don't work, problem the same!

Answer (score 116):

Step 1:
Added a config file in `~/.ssh/config` file which looks like

```
   User git
   Hostname gitlab.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
   TCPKeepAlive yes
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Step 2: Just clone the git repo WITHOUT sudo.

Documentation: https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths

** sometimes you have the config in your `~/.ssh/config`, but, IdentityFile path is not correct. you can check the file name like this `ls ~/.ssh/`. the file is normally is `id_ed25519` for gitlab. thus the correct config is `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

Comment: This is required if the key-file with the default name is already used for different purposes. If you are creating a key-file with non-default name, like `id_rsa_gitlab` in Fedo's example, you will need to supply a config-file. Gitlab's nice article about the matter: https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths

Comment: This worked for me.  I had both Github & Gitlab keys, so that you for this solution.

Comment: I have to change `Hostname` to `Host`to make this working

Comment: This work for me on Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04 WSL in Hyper terminal

Comment: The important part here is that `IdentityFile` is the private part; you should match this file with the `*.pub` public key which you've uploaded to Gitlab. Mixing one private key with another public key will fail, intentionally. Gitlab authenticates you because you have a matching pair of files.

Comment: thank you guy, you are my hero. I spend a lot of time across stackoverflow for finding solutions, but eventually your answer helped me!!!

Comment: Important to note. If you are using multiple gitlab domains. Like 
gitlab.com
gitlab.abc.com etc. 
you need to create a config file at ```~/.ssh/config``` and follow this answer. It solved for me

Answer (score 76):

I think the simple solution is to add private key to authentication agent (if your key is not `~/.ssh/id_rsa`),

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<your private key>
```

You basically let the `ssh-agent` take care of it.

Additionally, you can [add it permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu).

Comment: it's the file with the extension .pub

Comment: No. Private key is the file without `.pub` extension.

Comment: Worked for me. I had the default config , so i typed :
~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
 in console and It worked . @Hussain thanks

Answer (score 25):

There is a very simple solution to this:
Instead of working with ssh - move to https.
to do this:
in your project folder you have a .git folder
in there - you have a config file - open it in a text editor
and change the line

> url =git@gitlab.com:yourname/yourproject.git

to

> url = https://gitlab.com/yourname/yourproject.git

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem it sidesteps it entirely.

Comment: That's the answer I was searching to avoid `ssh` and use `https` way.

Comment: http doesn't allow me to make a `git push -f`, only `git push`

Comment: This worked, thanks. @UpAndAdam this sidesteps the issue, sure, but `ssh` is so problematic and frustrating on Windows that I would rather sidestep it. I'd rather get work done than wrestle with `ssh`.

Comment: Your personal anecdote is meaningless.  That doesn't make it an answer to the question asked.  It is a workaround and does not answer the question.  Furthermore windows is NOT tagged in the question and Ubuntu is. So your anecdote has no relevance

Answer (score 23):

In my case it did not work in the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

When I start the WSL, I must

- start ssh-agent_ `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`
- add the key to the ssh-agent: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
- if prompted, enter the password

Now the connection works.
We can test this with `ssh -T git@github.com`

notes:

- [weasel-pageant](https://github.com/vuori/weasel-pageant) allows us to reuse the ssh keys that are loaded in [PuTTY pageant](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) inside the WSL
- detailed explanation: [Git via SSH from Windows returns Permission Denied](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Git-via-SSH-from-Windows-returns-Permission-Denied/m-p/12833/highlight/true#M4161)

Answer (score 19):

if you are in Linux or macox , just try this in terminal:

```html
ssh-add -l
```

if it return nothing, try this:

```html
ssh-add
```

it must create identity in ~/.ssh/id_rsa

after retry :

```html
ssh-add -l
```

it must return your identity, so after retry to clone, it's must work

NB: don't forget to add your ssh key in your profile gitlab

thanks

Comment: Constantly returns `The agent has no identities.`

Comment: you save my day, thank you!

Answer (score 18):

make sure you are not running `sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:project/somethiing.git`, otherwise ssh will look in `/root/.ssh` instead of the key you uploaded `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Thank u man. My company require the project em / folder. I had to gerenate ssh using sudo. That way, i can use sudo git clone. Your advice helped me a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Steps to be done, got same error but i fixed it.
Gitlab wants ssh-rsa so below is the code to run ssh for rsa

1. `ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "name@gmail.com"`

name@gmail.com is your gitlab account email

2. It will prompt you to enter so just hit Enter after the below code is prompt,

   Enter file in which to save the key (/home/yourDesktopName/.ssh/id_rsa):
3. It will prompt again you to enter so just hit Enter after the below code is prompt,

   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
4. It will prompt again for the last you to enter so just hit Enter after the below code is prompt,

   Enter same passphrase again:
5. You will show your ssh-rsa generate.
6. Login to your Gitlab account and Go to the right navbar you will get setting and in the left sidebar you will get ssh key. Enter in it.
7. Look above the prompt asking you to enter, you will get the path of ssh-rsa.
8. Go to your SSH folder and get the id_rsa.pub
9. Open it and get the key and  Copy Paste to the Gitlab and you are nearly to done.
10. Check by: `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`
11. You will get: `Welcome to GitLab, @joy4!`
12. Done.

Comment: thanks. this works on windows 10. I tried ed25519 as gitlab instructed but not working.

Comment: This answer is pretty good - not sure why its not voted higher.

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me. Also tried on Win10

Answer (score 9):

I know, I'm answering this very late and even StackOverflow confirmed if I really want to answer. I'm answering because no one actually described the actual problem so wanted to share the same.

### The Basics

First, understand that what is the remote here. Remote is GitLab and your system is the local so when we talk about the remote `origin`, whatever URL is set in your `git remote -v` output is your remote URL.

### The Protocols

Basically, Git clone/push/pull works on two different protocols majorly (there are others as well)-

1. HTTP protocol
2. SSH protocol

When you clone a repo (or change the remote URL) and use the HTTPs URL like https://gitlab.com/wizpanda/backend-app.git then it uses the first protocol i.e. HTTP protocol.

While if you clone the repo (or change the remote URL) and uses the URL like `git@gitlab.com:wizpanda/backend-app.git` then it uses the SSH protocol.

### HTTP Protocol

In this protocol, every remote operation i.e. clone, push & pull uses the simple authentication i.e. username & password of your remote (GitLab in this case) that means for every operation, you have to type-in your username & password which might be cumbersome.

So when you push/pull/clone, GitLab/GitHub authenticate you with your username & password and it allows you to do the operation.

If you want to try this, you can switch to HTTP URL by running the command `git remote set-url origin <http-git-url>`.

To avoid that case, you can use the SSH protocol.

### SSH Protocol

A simple SSH connection works on public-private key pairs. So in your case, GitLab can't authenticate you because you are using SSH URL to communicate. Now, GitLab must know you in some way. For that, you have to create a public-private key-pair and give the public key to GitLab.

Now when you push/pull/clone with GitLab, GIT (SSH internally) will by default offer your private key to GitLab and confirms your identity and then GitLab will allow you to perform the operation.

So I won't repeat the steps which are already given by Muhammad, I'll repeat them theoretically.

1. Generate a key pair `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "My Common SSH Key"
2. The generated key pair will be by default in `~/.ssh` named `id_rsa.pub` (public key) & `id_rsa` (private key).
3. You will store the public key to your GitLab account (the same key can be used in multiple or any server/accounts).
4. When you clone/push/pull, GIT offers your private key.
5. GitLab matches the private key with your public key and allows you to perform.

### Tips

You should always create a strong rsa key with at least 2048 bytes. So the command can be `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`.

https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair

### General thought

Both the approach have their pros & cons. After I typed the above text, I went to search more about this because I never read something about this.

I found this official doc https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols which tells more about this. My point here is that, by reading the error and giving a thought on the error, you can make your own theory or understanding and then can match with some Google results to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it wasn't a gitlab problem, but a sshd configuration one. The ssh server didn't allow connection except for a list of users. The user git, the one connecting remotely to gitlab, wasn't in that list. So, check this before anything else.

You can check your ssh server configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If you have a line with the option `AllowUsers`, add git to it:

```
AllowUsers user1 user2 user3 git
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to project directory in terminal using `cd path/to/project`
2. Run `ssh-keygen`
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> for passphrase
4. Run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in terminal
5. Copy the key that you get at the terminal
6. Go to `Gitlab/Settings/SSH-KEYS`
7. Paste the key and press *Add Key* button

This worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

I have gitlab running with docker, this is what I did to fix my problem.

Found that inside docker **/var/log/gitlab/sshd/current** there were multiple occurences of a message:

> Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys

After which I changed ownership of that file from *99:users* to *git:users* with:

> chown git:users authorized_keys

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I'm running Gitlab on Kubernetes and the /gitlab-data directory (which is also the mountpoint for authorized_keys) had permission problems. A simple chown was enough.

Comment: @DillenMeijboom what was the chown permission that you needed to set? I'm suspecting a similar issue on mine but I'm not sure what to set the gitlab-data mount directory to.

Answer (score 4):

> When you have multiple git account and you want different ssh key
>
> You have to follow same step for generating the ssh key, but be sure
>   you

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your-email-id@gmail.com"
```

Enter the path you want to save(Ex: my-pc/Desktop/.ssh/ed25519)

Add the public key to your gitlab ([How to adding ssh key to gitlab](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair))

> You have to new ssh identity using the below comand

```
ssh-add ~/my-pc/Desktop/.ssh/ed25519
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution in [gitlab help](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths).

```
To create a new SSH key pair: 
 1. Open a terminal on Linux or macOS, or Git Bash / WSL on Windows.
 2. Generate a new ED25519 SSH key pair: ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com"
 2.1 Or, if you want to use RSA: ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
 3. Next, you will be prompted to input a file path to save your SSH key pair to... use the suggested path by pressing Enter
 4. Once the path is decided, you will be prompted to input a password to secure your new SSH key pair. It's a best practice to use a password, but it's not required and you can skip creating it by pressing Enter twice.
 5. Copy your public SSH key to the clipboard by using one of the commands below depending on your Operating System:
        macOS:        pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
        WSL / GNU/Linux (requires the xclip package):      xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
        Git Bash on Windows:      cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip
 6. Navigating to SSH Keys and pasting your public key in the Key field
 7. Click the Add key button
```

I hope it can help some of you!

Answer (score 4):

Earlier it was very difficult for me but when I tried it became so easy to add ssh key in Mac and Linux. There are a few steps and command to do this as follows:

1. Open a terminal of your system and move inside your project directory by the command:

```sh
cd 'project directory name'
```

2. Run command `ssh-keygen` in that terminal and enter it until the key's randomart image appears there.
3. Then enter one more command in that terminal:

```sh
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

It will generate your ssh key. Key will start with `ssh-rsa` and end with `.local`.

4. Copy the key and go to your Gitlab profile section then `ssh key` section and paste it there. Click on the `Add` button this will work.

Answer (score 4):

this way working for me.

1. add ssh / rsa keys to gitlab
2. `ssh-add` (type your terminal)
3. for verified type - `ssh -vT git@gitlab.com`

Comment: ssh-add was that I was missing! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I spent many hours to fix this. Below solution worked for me.

Follow these commands on your terminal.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "<your email address>" -b 4096 -t ed25519
```

Rename generated keys as this: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub the Add generated public key to your gitlab server.

Then add ssh key to ssh agent as below.

- Initiate ssh-agent

  eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
- If your key is generated with a different name, replace id_rsa in the command below

  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

To test the connection use this command.

```
ssh -T git@<git lab server url>
```

To troubleshoot use below commands.

```
ssh -Tv git@<git lab server url>
ssh -vvv git@<git lab server url>
```

Now you can clone your project to your local environment.

Answer (score 4):

For me this happened after a software update on Mac OS.
I first had this problem:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

and fixed it running

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Next I had this problem

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

And I could fix it simply with

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by adding a new ssh key:

1. `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com"`
2. Copy your public SSH key to the clipboard (`xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` in my case on Linux )
3. On gitlab, go to `settings=>ssh` keys and past the new key

Comment: Since rsa is an old algorithm, using a new one such as ed25519 as @ColdFire used is a better choice when creating ssh key with ssh-keygen . Using GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone ssh://git@<bitbucket URL>:<bitbucket port>/<project key>/<repository slug>.git show detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using **Windows 10** and nothing else working for him/her:

In my case, I had to clone the repo with **https** instead of ssh and a window popped-up asking for my credentials.
After that everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Two things mainly

1. You must have id_rsa.pub and id_rsa (private) keys in your .ssh folder ( which should be in your home folder.Create it if it isn't there put your keys ). It wouldn't work If you have named your key files differently
2. Change the permission of the id_rsa as chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 2):

Another issue that can cause this behaviour is when you have a setup with 2 possible %HOME%-locations.

I'm using a PC where some of my documents are stored locally, and some of them are stored on a network drive. Some applications think `C:\Users\<MyUserName>\` is my `%home%`, others think that `U:\` is the home.

Turns out `ssh-keygen` put my private key under `C:\users\<MyUserName>\`, and that `ssh -T` and `ssh -v` also look there.

So everything seems to work fine, except that `git clone`, `git push` and others look for a key in `U:\`.
Which fails, so I get the aforementioned error.

It took me an hour to find out, but in the end the solution was simple: I copied everything from `C:\Users\<MyUserName>\.ssh` to `U:\.ssh`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me on Windows 10 using Pageant as SSH agent, except adding a enviroment variable to windows (translated from german Windows 10, so the naming may differ):

1. Search for "variables"
2. Open System Enviroment Variables
3. Click Enviroment Variables button at the bottom
4. Add a new key named "GIT_SSH" and the value "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe", to the top section "User Variables xxx"
5. And you're done.

All thanks go to Benjamin Bortels, source: https://bortels.io/blog/git-in-vs-code-unter-windows-richtig-einstellen

Comment: Works after resatrt Windows 11 only.

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this..

Generated a key for Windows using this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096
```

but the problem was that after running this command, it popped a line:
"Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa): "
Here, I was giving only file name because of which my key was getting saved in my pwd and not in the given location. When I did "git clone ", it was assuming the key to be at "/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa" location but it was not found, hence it was throwing error.

At the time of key generation 2 files were generated say "file1" & "file1.pub". I renamed both these files as

```
file1 -> id_rsa
```

and

```
file1.pub -> id_rsa.pub
```

and placed both in the location `"/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/"`

Answer (score 1):

Go to  the terminal and regenerate the ssh key again. Type  `ssh-keygen`. It will ask you where you want to save it, type the path.

Then copy the public key to gitlabs platform. It usually starts with ssh-rsa.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was, that I switched `UsePAM` from `yes` to `no` in the SSH configuration file under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. With `UsePAM yes` everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**How to add SSH key to gitlab account in ubuntu?**

1. Open terminal in your project directory.
2. Type ‘ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your gitlab email" ’ and hit enter
3. Type ‘vim /home/mnbtech/.ssh/id_rsa.pub’ and hit enter
   (or manually open your 'id_rsa.pub'from where you saved it)
4. SSH key will appear. Copy those and
5. Go to your gitlab account.
6. Click profile image And click setting
7. In left side select SSH-Keys
8. Then paste those key
   Click add key

SSH-Key will be added!

(N.B if you have Generate Previews SSH Key and Getting permission denied (public key). You Delete Your Previews ssh key and Generate new one and add git user.name and email on your terminal )

Comment: What is different in that answer than in the previous instructions?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be differences between the two ways to access a git repository i.e. using either SSH or HTTPS. For me, I encountered the error because I was trying to push my local repository using SSH.

The problem can simply be solved by clicking the clone button on the landing page of your project and the copying the HTTPS link and replacing it to the SSH link appearing with the format "git@gitlab...".

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, 
It has been fixed after I re-generate the ssh key inside .ssh folder without naming it (keep it as id_rsa.pub).
Then add it again to gitlab ssh key.
Everything working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

**I solved `git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey)` issue using following instructions**

1. RUN `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. Copy `id_rsa.pub` (public key) to your getlab `Setting -> SSH Keys
3. RUN `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
4. Copy `id_rsa` (private key) to `Code_repo->git_auth->id_rsa

**NOTE:** Take care of the machine user if you are using `root` user in your DockerFile or anywhere else then use `sudo su` before running the above commands to get root user public and private keys.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, it wasn't a problem on the user/client side, but on the Gitlab server side.

We are running a local Gitlab CE 12.9 instance on CentOS 7.1.

We found out that on the server, the *.ssh/authorized_keys* file was not updating properly. Users create their SSH keys (following the Gitlab guide) and add it to the Gitlab server, but the server does not update the *authorized_keys*, so it will always result to permission denied errors.

A workaround was to [rebuild the authorized_keys file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/raketasks/maintenance.html#rebuild-authorized_keys-file) by running:

```
$ sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:shell:setup
```

That would work for anyone who added their keys *before* running the rake task. For the next users who would add their keys, someone has to manually run the rake tasks again.

A more permanent solution was to *not* use the *authorized_keys* file and use instead an [indexed lookup on the Gitlab database](http://192.168.1.61/help/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup#setting-up-fast-lookup-via-gitlab-shell):

> GitLab Shell provides a way to authorize SSH users via a fast, indexed
>   lookup to the GitLab database. GitLab Shell uses the fingerprint of
>   the SSH key to check whether the user is authorized to access GitLab.
>
> Add the following to your `sshd_config` file. This is usually located at
>   `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but it will be `/assets/sshd_config` if you're
>   using Omnibus Docker:
>
> ```
> Match User git    # Apply the AuthorizedKeysCommands to the git user only   
>   AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell-authorized-keys-check git %u %k   
>   AuthorizedKeysCommandUser git 
> Match all    # End match, settings apply to all users again
> ```
>
> Reload OpenSSH:
>
> ```
> # Debian or Ubuntu installations   
> sudo service ssh reload
>
> # CentOS installations   
> sudo service sshd reload
> ```
>
> Confirm that SSH is working by removing your user's SSH key in the UI, adding a new one, and attempting to pull a repo.

By default (well the default on our installation), the *Write to authorized_keys file* was checked in the *Admin Area > Performance Optimization* settings. So we unchecked that and used the Gitlab database instead.

[image]

After setting up indexed lookup and unchecking the *Write to authorized_keys file*, SSH access became OK.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,I use Ubuntu there are two users, one is admin user and other is me,I created "*id_rsa*" and "*id_rsa.pub*" file while logged in as me(normal user), these files get created in your ".ssh" folder inside your home folder,
it might not be found cause it is hidden, so make it visible, to check if the files are in it.

So the files got created in "*home/.ssh*" in my user profile, but while pushing the code into gitlab I logged in as admin in the terminal,
using command: **su - adminName** (it prompts to enter password after this)

so ssh private key is not found in "*adminhome/.ssh*" folder . So to solve this you can:

1. create "*id_rsa*" and "*id_rsa.pub*" in the admin profile (or)
2. Push the code into gitlab using your profile instead of Admin profile.

Answer (score 1):

< Git looks at ssh keys by name, picking the ones starting with id_ first... In case there are two ssh keys with names starting with id_ it tries both and see if one of them is fine. If your ssh key name starts with a different name you need to change it.

Example:

keyssh (private key)    **change the name to-->** id_rsa (private key)
keyssh.pub (public key) **change the name to-->** id_rsa.pup (public key)
< I also created a file named "**config**" in the .ssh folder.
The "**config**" file has no extension and is needed for correct configuration/management of the **ssh key**:

[image]
< Also, I added the login credentials and the network domain in the **windows credential manager**:

Internet or network address: **https://corporate-gitlab.xxxxx.com**
Username: **username@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com**
Password: **••••••••••**

**This way I solved the error:**

```
git@corporate-gitlab.xxxxxxx.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

I added my `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the list of known SSH Keys in my GitLab settings https://gitlab.com/profile/keys. That solved the problem for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use ubuntu 18.04, and it was actually permission issue in my local machine. The issue was gone when I set read/write permission to my .git folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had this same problem and after trying the answer @Khan proposed. However, I was only able to make it work by just changing the origin url in the .git/config file to the https address : https://gitlab.com/mygitlabusername/mygitproject.git

Since access via ssh is denied, I figured out using https shouldn't be a problem. It will however ask for your username and password for each push to the at repository

Answer (score 0):

Please use `git config credential.helper store` if your site is using TLS/SSL. 
Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Change permission :: chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
It helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `git clone XXX` if you'd see `LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to XXX` it **might** be the case that just updated your OS, installed some dev tools, e.g. Xcode with its tools on Mac, VPN, Antivirus (especially Kaspersky Antivirus) or something between/other.

In my case simply restarting my OS (macOS Catalina) fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I used a non-root user with sudo access. But even `sudo git clone ...` didn't work. The solution was to create the folder for the project, `chown user projectfolder` and then run the clone without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue because of ssh-agent conflicts on Windows-10.
If you are using Windows-10 as well then please go through my detailed solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173335/14021241)

If you are not on windows-10 then please check if:

1. your ssh-agent is running
2. correct private key is added to your ssh-agent
3. correct public key is added to your github account (You are able to clone, so this step should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

After creating your SSH keys, you simply need to add the Public key which is usually named as:

`id_rsa.pub`

OR

`id_ed25519.pub`

by using the latest working URL of GitLab which is:

https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys/

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but make sure your system and your git client are using the same ssh client. This is probably the most relevant on Windows.

When you install modern versions of Windows, OpenSSH client gets installed by default, and when you install Git for Windows, internally it uses its own bundled ssh client. So, you need to point Git for Windows to your OpenSSH install.

Same goes for any other 3rd party ssh clients, we will just take OpenSSH as our client of choice here.

1. Win + R => cmd
2. `where ssh` - Get OpenSSH path if installed
3. Win + S => 'Edit environment variables ...'
4. System variables => look for `GIT_SSH` key
5. Edit it or create if doesn't exist, set OpenSSH path as its value
6. Create a new terminal instance where the changes should now be applied and you should be good to go.

Note that if you're using VS Code or some other editor that has integrated terminals simply creating a new one won't cut it, you need to restart your editor.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after updating to 12.9.2, I needed to update my sshd_config file to use the Authorized command keys directive.

Everything is explained in the documentation here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup.html

Once I restarted ssh, the key worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

if you guys tried all the previous answer and didn't work, might you need look at this.
for me the situation is change repository's remote url from https to ssh.
and the url paste false
the correct is

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@gitlab.***.com:123456/project.git
```

then i past is

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.***.com:123456/project.git
```

the problem found after i clone a new project then look up new repository's remote url