# npm install with git+ssh doesn't use existing ssh key for user

Tags: git, github, npm, ssh

I want to reference a private GitHub repo in my project. I'm trying commands like:

`npm i git+ssh://git@github.com/<myusername>/<myprivaterepo>.git`

However it seems to not notice that I have SSH keys already configured on my (Windows 11) system. I can happily clone the repo, but executing the above command instead prompts me to sign in to GitHub:

[image: GitHub Sign In]

According to my searches online, this should work without additional authentication. For example, [this article](https://tolotra.com/2018/11/10/how-to-use-private-git-repo-as-npm-package/) explains how to set this up - I can skip steps 2 and 3 as my SSH key already works (verified with `ssh -T git@github.com`), but I still get a prompt, and I don't want to add unnecessary additional access to my GitHub account where it isn't technically needed.

Does anyone know why I am getting this prompt?

Answer (score 6):

I figured this out myself - it's apparently a common issue in a variety of contexts, but in my search around npm related commands, I didn't find anywhere referencing this happening with npm, hence my question.

Thanks to [this comment I stumbled upon](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26743#issuecomment-332040672), I discovered there's a setting for controlling handling credentials. You can check its value with `git config credential.helper`. I was blissfully ignorant that this existed as I normally use SSH key pairs from the command line.

I solved my issue by turning off the credential helper completely for git on my system, with:

`git config --system --unset credential.helper`

Note that this required administrative privileges to do, as the relevant config file lives in the `Program Files` directory (`C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig`).

Comment: After that, since I use Windows, I also had to run `start-ssh-agent` (and not `ssh-agent`) to get it to work. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173335/5905695

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the git ssh private key is not stored on the  jenkins host，you need use the private key from jenkins credential,with version 2.30+ git,git support use GIT_SSH_COMMAND to set private key,the code in jenkinsfile as bellow

```
 stage('install') {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "keyId", keyFileVariable: 'key')]) {
                // from git 2.30+,git support use GIT_SSH_COMMAND to set private key 
                sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $key" npm install'
                }
     }
```