# How to use https with gitlab.com?

Tags: gitlab

A while back I was able to use `https` with `gitlab.com`. I am currently using a company that I don't want to add to ssh key to gitlab, so I tried to use https to pull and push on gitlab.com but it seems like I kept getting 500 error.

I remember I have to add some token for this but I don't remember exactly how I can use https with gitlab and there seems to be no documentation for this.

Comment: This is accessed/documented at `User Settings` > `Access Tokens`.

Comment: You can consider using a gpg key or if that won't help as other mentioned you may consider following the access tokens approach. Creating a PAT is very well explained here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token

The command should be `git clone https://<username>:<private-token>@gitlab.anydomainhere.com/developers/<projectname>.git
`

Comment: SEE ANSWER THERE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082435/6639353

Comment: @Elad where is the oauth part in your answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting permission denied (public key) on gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427498/getting-permission-denied-public-key-on-gitlab)

Answer (score 3):

First you must generate an access token from: `https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens`

Then you can use `https://oauth2:ACCESS_TOKEN@somegitlab.com/vendor/package.git` to access your project.