# Cannot push on a new remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I've created  a remote repository on my local Gitlab server and I'm trying to push the local content but it's asking me for my pass but now for my user

```
$ git push -u origin master
git@192.168.0.6's password:
```

I've tried with my user's pass and the root pass and it doesn't work, what pass is asking for??

Comment: Is the URL of the remote `git@192.168.0.6:AccountName/RepoName` or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting permission denied (public key) on gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427498/getting-permission-denied-public-key-on-gitlab)

Comment: Use `192.168.0.6` instead of `gitlab.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting through ssh (i.e. not through the git daemon), it is asking the password of the `git` user on the machine. In this case, you may want to change the remote to `<your username>@192.168.0.6`.

Answer (score 0):

The git URL structure is: 
`protocol://username:password@gitlab.company.com/group/project.git` 
Example: 
`http://git:123@gitlab.url/main/sales.git`

Git will ask for user if you do not set the user name in the URL so you need to set a new URL by using this command 
`$ git remote set-url`
Like this
`$ git remote set-url origin http://gitlab.company.com/group/project.git`