# Gitkraken - gitlab pull failed (WSAStartup)

Tags: git, gitlab, winsock2, gitkraken, wsastartup

[gitkraken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWyF7.png)

I have encountered an issue with GitKraken or GitLab. It appeared suddenly. The problem is that I am unable to use any of the built-in GitKraken features, such as pull or push. However, when I open the terminal, everything works fine.

First I tried to fix winsock using cmd : *netsh winsock reset.*
Then I did following steps: [Getting permission denied (public key) on gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427498/getting-permission-denied-public-key-on-gitlab) that was the point when terminal starts working (I mean git pull/push).
I also changed gitlab token, added new ssh key, reinstall git and reintegrated gitlab account with gitkraken